# функция mail() в php ubuntu nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sendmail, phpmailer, php-nginx

есть сервер на системе ubuntu на котором установлен nginx нужно чтоб при регистрации отправлялся email на почту которую зарегистрировали пользуюсь функцией mail() В php но сообщение неотпрвляется не могу понять почему может что то нужно установить на сервер или что исправить в каком нибуль файле??? На локальном хосте все работает

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['to'];
$from = "a@gmail.com";
$subject = "fsfs";

$body = "this is auto message";

$from_new = "from: $from";

mail($email,$subject,$body,$from_new);
?>
```

ввел эту команду

```
<?php
echo  mail ("my_exist@gmail.com","test message",
             "test message","From:no-reply@gmail.com");


?> выдает 1 что это значит и как все таки настроить чтоб сообщение отправлялось. Заранее спасибо за ответы
```

Comment: $_POST['to'] корректный (попробуйте разные0? sendmail стоит? сервера службу перезапускали поставив sendmail? что если убрать последний параметр? еще у sendmail есть лог...

Comment: @Rou1997 sendmail поставил но может его нужно как то подкоректировать а если убрать последний параметр то откуда будет отправляться сообщение

Comment: раз не работает - то хоть бы откуда отправлялось, такой должен быть принцип

Comment: @Rou1997 убрал последний параметр так же неработает((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с sendmail. Удалил sendmail() поставил postfix все заработало как должно было!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй проверится на наличие твоего IP в спам базах [здесь](https://2ip.ru/spam/).
Возможно тебе повезло и твой IP попал именно туда. Из - за этого письма могут не приходить, так как почтовые системы будут расценивать их как спам.

Comment: спасибо проверил но все в порядке вопрос остается открытым((( вы случайно не знаете как правильно настроить работу sendmail я все таки грешу на это

Comment: я кое что добавил посмотрите пожалуйста может это вам поможет понять мою проблему

Comment: @Sergey , 1 = TRUE. Значит письмо по идее отправлено. Это не обозначает, что оно было получено. Если бы sendmail работал неправильно, то он скорее всего выдал 0 (FALSE). Я уверен, что на сервере Google Mail есть проверка достоверности сообщения. Я очень сомневаюсь вот тут: "From:no-reply@gmail.com". В гугле работают не дураки. Отсылка с несуществующей почты выглядит очень подозрительно.  Попробуй повторить данный эксперимент с использованием существующих email'ов.

Comment: пробовал безрезультатно

Comment: сообщения почему то неотправлются а идут в отложенное

Comment: То есть получается, что у вас на локальке всё работало, вы перешли на хостинг и всё перестало работать?

Comment: ну для локалки я использовал xamp сервер и там ничего устанавливать не надо было просто работал код а тут немного другая история

Comment: Поищи логи здесь: /var/log/syslog . Напиши примерное содержание одного из них.

Comment: Aug 10 18:33:51 test sm-mta[5007]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mxs.mail.ru., version=                TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Aug 10 18:33:54 test sm-mta[5007]: v7AG2miI003062: to=<serg@mail.ru>, ct                laddr=<www-data@test.wt> (33/33), delay=02:31:06, xdelay=00:00:07, mailer=esmtp,                 pri=1560336, relay=mxs.mail.ru. [94.100.180.104], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: 421                 Problem resolving DNS for domain ns@gmail.com (Domain name is syntactica                lly invalid)

Comment: как я понял не проходит проверку "verify=FAIL" и проблема с именем домена но как это исправить

Comment: Это какая - то проблема с DNS. Возможно тут ошибка связана с тем, что почтовый сервис не может найти ns@gmail.com.

Comment: на другие адреса тоже не отправляет

Comment: как поменять этот Domain ns@gmail.com и на какой

Comment: Не знаю... видимо какая - то ошибка в sendmail, но я в нём не разбираюсь, если честно.